# Using jQuery validate to ensure at least one dropdown has a value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, selectlist

I am new to jQuery, jQuery validate, and JavaScript so I apologize in advance for my ignorance.  I have spent hours looking for an answer and trying different code but I haven't been able to figure what seems like should be simple.

To keep things simple, I have two dropdowns.  One for Apples and one for Oranges.  I want to ensure that at least one dropdown has a value when the form is submitted using the "Approve" button. If neither dropdown has a value then the form shouldn't be submitted and a notice next to each field should state something like "At least one dropdown must have a value".  When one dropdown is then selected, the warning for both dropdowns goes away.

The form code is:

```
    <form name="form1" id="form1" action="" method="post">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="selApples">Apples</label></td>
      <td><select name="selApples" id="selApples" class="authSelect">
          <option value="">None</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="selOranges">Oranges</label></td>
      <td><select name="selOranges" id="selOranges" class="authSelect">
          <option value="">None</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <input type="button" name="btnApprove" id="btnApprove" value="Approve">
        <input type="button" name="btnCancel" id="btnCancel" value="Cancel">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

I would post my attempt at the jQuery but at the risk of embarrassing myself, I won't.  Does anyone have any ideas on the best way to tackle this?

EDIT:  Since it was pointed out I should use require_from_group here is my attempt:

```
$("#btnApprove").on("click", function() {

    $("#form1").validate( {
        ignore: "",
        rules: {    
            selApples: {
                require_from_group: [1, ".authSelect"]
            },              
            selOranges: {
                require_from_group: [1, ".authSelect"]
            }
        }       
    });

});
```

Comment: You simply need to include [the `additional-methods.js` file](http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.14.0/additional-methods.js) and employ the `require_from_group` rule.

Comment: Thanks.  I did try the require_from_group but I guess because I'm not versed in this yet I couldn't get it to work.  I'll give it another try I guess.

Comment: If you already tried that, then you should have mentioned it in your question and shown your code attempt so we could help you get it working.

Comment: *"I would post my attempt at the jQuery but at the risk of embarrassing myself, I won't."* ~ You are fully expected to show your code attempt so that we can help you, otherwise, your question is not as easy to answer nor is it helpful to others reading this in the future.

Comment: As I mentioned, I tried almost everything I could find.  I had no idea which was the right track which is why I didn't post the code.

Comment: Did you look at other questions yet?  See:  http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjquery-validate%5D+require_from_group

Comment: I have now posted code along the lines of the require_from_group method you talked about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your `require_from_group` rule.  The issue is that you've wrapped the `.validate()` method inside of a `click` handler.

The `.validate()` method is how the plugin is *initialized*, it's never called by the form's button.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#form1").validate({ // intialize plugin
        ignore: "",
        rules: {    
            selApples: {
                require_from_group: [1, ".authSelect"]
            },              
            selOranges: {
                require_from_group: [1, ".authSelect"]
            }
        }       
    });

    $("#btnApprove").on("click", function() {
        $("#form1").valid(); // trigger validation
    });

});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/0arvubxy/**

- If you want to combine the two error messages into one, then you would use the `groups` option.
- If you need to move the error message, then use the `errorPlacement` option.

Comment: Thank you Sparky.  I appreciate the help.  That's what I was looking for.